# In Ruby, how to send multiple files in single request using RESTClient

Tags: ruby, rubygems, controller, rest-client

I've been have a issue where I tried to use the RestClient lib to send two or more files to Kotlin Service endpoint where this controller needs to receive a files attributes that is a `List<MultipartFile>`.

I'm using rest-client (2.0.2), rails (7.0.4.2) and ruby 3.1.2p20

I already try send this requests, but a receive a bad request and in the kotlin service says:

> "Required request part 'files' is not present"

```
 request = @http_client_class.new(
          method: :post,
          url: path,
          payload: { multipart: true, files: files },
          headers: build_header(headers)
        )
```

I tried this way but the hash in ruby just accept one key per hash, so it just send the second file. And yes I already try to use `compare_by_identity` method doesn't work

```
request = @http_client_class.new(
  method: :post,
  url: path,
  payload: {
    :multipart => true,
    :files => files[0],
    :files => files[1]
  },
  headers: build_header(headers)
)
```

I already tried this but I also receive a bad request and in the kotlin service says "Required request part 'files' is not present"

```
payload = {
  file1: File.new(file1_path, 'rb'),
  file2: File.new(file2_path, 'rb')
}
```

And other alternatives that chatgpt, phind and Stack Overflow gave to me.

The curious is when I send one file it works. Request like this

```
 request = @http_client_class.new(
          method: :post,
          url: path,
          payload: { multipart: true, files: files[0] },
          headers: build_header(headers)
        )
```

It looks when I have a list the lib RestClient use `Utils.flatten_params` they change my attributes name from `files` to `files[]`.

**RESOLUTION**

I resolved change the lib

Using Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart works.

Comment: how about zip them first ?

Comment: Its not works because the server is not prepare to receive a zip.